# About this Goddess -Skull Cup and Paasam in HER hands

Tags: identification-request, goddess, devi

Has any one heard about this Goddess, who is having "**Paasam**" in one hand and 
"**Skull-cup**" in another hand  and having 3 eyes and sitting on a Lotus.
"***kamalaasanastham***" ...
Is this goddess a Roudramoorthi/Thaamasika bhaava moorti?

Comment: Do you have any picture/photo?

Comment: Could be maatangi devi..

Comment: @Pandya, sry, i dont have any pic. i saw the text somewhere .i just read about it.

Comment: @rakesh, does maaatangi has paasam?, i am not sure, whats the bhaava or sankalpa abt the Goddess am talking abt . But know this much only. Not clear whether SHE has 4 arms or 2 arms. Dont know about Maatangi Devi. Please elaborate a little bit if you know about Maatangi and HER sankalpam or Avastha. Thnx..

Comment: @SaMolPP what sankalpam you talking about ? What are you going to do with these details.

Comment: There are many goddesses who hold a Pasa.. So either u give the complete Dhyana Sloka or post a pic of the deity... Otherwise it is difficult to identify from the info u hv given. @SaMolPP

Comment: @Rickross ,  my question is, the goddess who is holding a Pasa and Skull-cup and having seated on a Lotus and having Trinetra. i  heard about Tripurasundari , but Tripurasundari doesnt have skull-cup. i heard about Tripura bhairavi,and Tripura bhairavi's dhyana is different. so may be some other goddess of whom, you experts may be aware of....                             
     My question itself, does anyone has the pic of the mentioned deity!! am unheard of .. thats why am requesting here..

Comment: Okay btw I am also a Roger Federer fan but he lost again in the SF at Paris... :( @SaMolPP But Basel win was great.

Comment: thanks ! @Rickross . nice to meet another Roger fan!!! me, RFan forever!! ALLEZ Roger!